# .htaccess доступы

Tags: .htaccess, веб-программирование

Как числовые урлы ссылать на 404?(мультиязычный сайт на wordpress под плагином Polylang) примеры:
http://foo.com/123432 && http://foo.com/bar/123432 
После ввода символов добавляет лишь слеш /12312/ и остается на current page, но никак не 404? 
Пробовал и RewriteRule не помогла

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пробуйте так

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*/)?\d+/?$
RewriteRule ^ - [R=404,L]
```

С какой версии апача работает редирект вне 300х кодов не помню, на версии 2.4 все отрабатывает.

Регулярка для фильтрации url

```
^(.*/)?\d+/?$
```

`^` - начало строки,
`(.*/)?` - необязательная группа, захватывает все символы от начала строки до слеша перед цифрами вместе со слешем,
`\d+` - от 1 до бесконечности цифр,
`/?` - необязательный слеш в конце строки,
`$` - конец строки.

Будет реагировать на `http://foo.com/123432` и на `http://foo.com/123432/`, на `http://foo.com/bar/123432` и на `http://foo.com/bar/123432/`.

Comment: спасибо) 
все как доктор прописал)